# Trying to load .json with jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, jsdom

I am trying to load a .json file into my program using .getJSON but for some reason it wont load

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom"); 
const { JSDOM } = jsdom; 
const { window} = new JSDOM(); 
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
...
   async function check(){
        $.getJSON('test.json', function(result){
                console.log("json: " + result);
        });
}

async function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  });
}
client.on("ready", async ()  => {
        console.log(`Bot is running! ${client.user.username}`);
        client.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]).then(link =>{
                console.log(link);
        }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err.stack);
        });
        while(1){
                await wait();
                await check();
        }
});

client.login(setup.key);
```

This is the code i am using, it is meant to check a certain file every few seconds. I want to check the file so that i can detect changes and then trigger a message.

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Describe "won't load". What happens when you call check()? Also, there's no point in declaring check async, since it 1) doesn't await anything, and 2) doesn't return anything.

Comment: How did you called check method?

Comment: did you try F12 and see error in console?

Comment: @HienNguyen This appears to be in node.js. The op used JSDom

Comment: 1. No i don't get any error messages, it just doesn't print
2. The async decleration was needed on some other code i had in this function before but now removed. Just did not remove the async yet ;)
3 The check methode is called from the client.on("ready", .... methode (discord.js). I am working on a discord bot

Comment: Hmm. Is there any specific reason you are using JSDom for importing a local json file? `require` works for local json files

Comment: I was told that u need to use getJSON in order to reload the file over and over again and that require would just load the file once and then use the first loaded content if you call it again

Comment: I see. How about using [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) instead. Simulating a browser and using jquery is really excessive

Comment: would readFile work with a .json file like it's supposed to though? Wouldn't i just get a String from that?

Comment: You can `JSON.parse` a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments here, found a way easier solution other then using jQUERY and .getJSON. Just use readFile and JSON.parse:

```
function check(){
        fs.readFile('test.json', (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(json);
        })
}
```